# Can I get the name of day with datetime_select Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have

```
= f.datetime_select :publish_date, discard_year: true, discard_minute: true, ampm: true
```

For the day it just gives an integer. It possible to get the name of the day also in the select box? ie

1, Thursday

2, Friday

3, Saturday

.
.
.
30, Name of day

Comment: Possible, show the code please.

Answer (score 1):

For rails DateHelper you only [these options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.htm) available, so I don't think you can use it the way you want, your only option is to build your own helper.